# Ruby on Rails: Cannot run the command 'heroku run rails db:seed'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just need this run this command in order for my Heroku application's to be in synced with my Workspace's database. But when I run this command, it says that I have 9 pending migrations. I ran rails db:migrate then heroku run rails db:seed, but I still have the same pending migrations.

Answer (score 1):

When you execute `rails db:migrate` it will migrate your local database. To migrate Heroku database you have to use this command `heroku run rails db:migrate`

Answer (score 0):

Below some steps  to run migration and check application in heroku

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
heroku run rake db:seed
```

I know you did it, but you also need to restart the dyno so it will load new schema with this command below

```
heroku restart
```

run the server

```
heroku ps:scale web=1
```

check the server status

```
heroku ps
```

if you get web.1: starting .... then your dyno is ready
you can open now with

```
heroku open
```